# Quel accord faut-il faire lorsque l'on parle implicitement d'un mot?

Tags: grammaire, accord

Dans cette phrase : « Par contre je n'ai jamais entendu *négation* utilisé**e** de cette manière. » devrais-je plutôt accorder *utilisé* avec mot (le *mot* négation) qui est sous-entendu ou avec *négation* directement ? Et ai-je le choix ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

De mon point de vue, le plus cohérent c'est:

- dans le cas où l'on parle du mot, utiliser l'italique et accorder au masculin
- dans le cas où l'on parle de négations (en omettant l'article), éviter l'italique et  accorder normalement.

Ici, il s'agit du premier cas, j'enlèverais donc le *e*.